# Dynamically add a property or method to an object in groovy

Tags: groovy, monkeypatching

Is it possible to add a property or a method to an object dynamically in Groovy? This is what I have tried so far:

```
class Greet {
  def name
  Greet(who) { name = who[0].toUpperCase() + [1..-1] }
  def salute() { println "Hello $name!" }
}

g = new Greet('world')  // create object
g.salute()              // Output "Hello World!"

g.bye = { println "Goodbye, $name" }
g.bye()
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Hello World!
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bye for class: Greet
Possible solutions: name
    at test.run(greet.groovy:11)
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you just want to add the `bye()` method to the single instance `g` of the class `Greet`, you need to do:

```
g.metaClass.bye = { println "Goodbye, $name" }
g.bye()
```

Otherwise, to add `bye()` to all instance of `Greet` (from now on), call

```
Greet.metaClass.bye = { println "Goodbye, $name" }
```

But you'd need to do this before you create an instance of the `Greet` class

[Here is a page on the per-instance metaClass](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_per_instance_metaclass)

[And here is the page on MetaClasses in general](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_metaclasses)

---

Also, there's a bug in your constructor.  You're missing `who` from infront of your `[1..-1]` and if the constructor is passed a `String` of less than 2 characters in length, it will throw an exception

A better version might be:

```
Greet( String who ) { 
  name = who.inject( '' ) { String s, String c ->
    s += s ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase()
  }
}
```

---

As metioned in  the comments,

```
Greet( String who ) { 
  name = who.capitalize()
}
```

is the proper way

Comment: I'd suggest using `name = who.capitalize()` in the constructor.

Comment: @ataylor I knew there'd be a better way than that `inject`! Cheers :-)

Comment: @tim_yates, if injecting a class function, such as `Greet.metaClass.bye = { ... }`, should that be done in `BootStrap.groovy` for a Grails app?

Comment: To add a property to instance, we can add getter to metaClass, ie: `g.metaClass.getPlanet() = { return 'World' }` Then we can use `g.planet`

Comment: Links to help are dead