# In Groovy what is equivalent for Kotlin extensions?

Tags: kotlin, groovy

In Kotlin I can use extensions, for example in that way:

```
fun String.append(addValue: String): String {
    return this + addValue;
}
```

Is there any similar way in groovy?

**UPDATE:**

Based on comments and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270027/groovy-dynamically-add-method-with-argument) the 'groovy' equivalent should looks like that:

```
String.metaClass.append = {String addValue -> delegate + addValue }
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954719/do-groovy-have-extension-methods-like-in-c

Comment: Also possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781936/dynamically-add-a-property-or-method-to-an-object-in-groovy

Comment: Yes, that was what i want to find.